# Using JavaScript properly in Shopware 6 App development

Tags: javascript, shopware6

I am building a shopware 6 app and I wonder how to properly use JavaScript code inside the app. Currently I am just adding an inline script tag inside the base.html.twig like so:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/base.html.twig' %}

{% block base_body %}
  {{ parent() }}

  <script type="module">
    (async function() {
      // my main app code goes here
    })();
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

This is horrible in many ways: there's no minification, obfuscatio or possibility to use TypeScript later on.
What am I missing? The older style plugin development is actually capable to use JavaScript code in their own files if they are located inside the 'Resoruces/app/' directory. But this is not documentated for the app development and didn't work anyways.
I hope for your advives. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pure storefront modifications (twig template and js/css changes) there are no real differences between the app and the plugin system, it works in the same way for both extension systems.

So there is no explicit documentation on how to make storefront changes, as the [documentation targeted for plugins](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-javascript) applies for apps as well.

The only difference is that in the app system you can not configure the path to your storefront files, so you have to put them into the `/Resources` folder in your app, as described in [this documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/storefront). **Note:** That is also the default location for plugin storefront files, but the plugin system allows to configure a custom location.

So in short it is totally possible to use minified js or type script in the app system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and clarification, that this approach should work with apps as well. But as I mentioned, it did not. I tried a simple console.log() and the cookie consent example, which both did not seem to work.

Comment: Please make sure that your app is installed and active, that can be one common issue.
The other common issue regarding storefront (especially js extensions) is that the js changes are not live directly, you have to rebuild the storefront js via webpack, so if you use a setup based on the production template run `./bin/build-storefront.sh` as described in the docs: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-javascript#testing-your-changes

In the output of webpack you should see that your app is added as a new entry point for code changes.

Comment: Okay I really should have read this article with more attention. It worked with building the storefront new,  but not with the psh.phar although I am using the dockware:dev image. Anyways thank you very much!